# Trigger Power Plan when an app is launched

Tags: windows-10, power-management, windows-11

Is there a way to trigger a customized power plan when the user launches a specific application?

Details:
I want the computer to switch to high performance mode with %100 CPU performance while launching abc.exe and turn back to default mode after closing it. Can you guide me?

There are softwares that do the similar thing but I want to do it with windows' power plan option.

For
Windows 11 user
Windows 10 user

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can script this in a .cmd file. If you doubleclick the batch script, it first sets the powerscheme, launches the game, and once the game closes, sets it back.

The only downside of this approach is, that a command window will appear during the game.

Using `powercfg /list` you can see the GUID's for a scheme, and then using `powercfg /setactive 12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab` you can activate one of the schemes.

See also `powercfg /? -setactive`  for more help and an example.